# Hardhat Polygon gas price error

Tags: gas, nft, ethers.js, hardhat, polygon

I'm developing a NFT minting API with Hardhat, Ethers and alchemyapi.

In [Rinkeby network](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x42aD50cBeD0c7631a5Ae53DA1568EF4fb2BFaB95) it's working!! But when I deployed my [contract to Polygon](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x33ea184f2fab11d99b70b594ef3359bdd12d4033) it's returning some erros when Mint function is called.

The first error was **transaction underpriced**, so I added this options
[image]

After that I'm getting a new error: **exceeds block gas limit**, if I reduce *gasPrice* and *gasLimit* values the first error backs.

My Solidity code: https://gist.github.com/matthsena/21362cde23d87c920feb2cc72a8d5512

Answer (score 1):

I met the same 'underpriced' problem when I switch to Polygon, and solved by using this option { gasPrice:50000000000,  gasLimit: 1000000 }, which means gasPrice = 50 Gwei